# Images in function don't works well even though image in body works

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code in the function. I think the problem is happening here.
There is no problem in image source I can assurance it.

```js
var src=document.getElementById("new");
var url = "";
var icon=new Image;
icon.setAttribute("src", url + "/favicon.ico");
icon.setAttribute("width", "100");
icon.setAttribute("length", "100");
src.appendChild(icon);

var text=document.createTextNode(url);
src.appendChild(text);

var del=new Image;
del.setAttribute("src", "delete.jpg");
del.setAttribute("width", "100");
del.setAttribute("length", "100");
src.appendChild(del);

var line=document.createElement("BR");
src.appendChild(line);
```

```html
<div id="new" />
```

```
var src=document.getElementById("new");

var icon=new Image;
icon.setAttribute("src", url + "/favicon.ico");
icon.setAttribute("width", "100");
icon.setAttribute("length", "100");
src.appendChild(icon)

var text=document.createTextNode(url);
src.appendChild(text);

var del=new Image;
del.setAttribute("src", "delete.jpg");
del.setAttribute("width", "100");
del.setAttribute("length", "100");
src.appendChild(del);

var line=document.createElement("BR");
src.appendChild(line);
```

This is Html when I run. There is no problem in the text, but the problem is happening in the image. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTnd5.png)

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's dev tools to see what the value of the images' `src` attributes are?

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying..... But, I don't think it is the problem. Images in body worked well.

Comment: It looks like your images *aren't* displaying. This is what you're asking for help with, correct?

Comment: @IronFlare Right. That's my question. Is there any solution?

Comment: If the images are not displaying, it might be a problem with the HTML. Search for "how to open dev tools" for your browser. Then, open this and look through the page's structure (usually located in a tab called "Elements" within the dev tools). Find the image and see what its `src="..."` attribute is.

Comment: Where are you setting the url path?